# Excel Crashing On Loop Through .FormatConditions

Tags: excel, vba

I try to reapply two existing conditional formatting rules to another column of a table.

If i run the following Code, Excel crashes completely (force close) on the second iteration of the for loop.

```
Dim fc As Variant
For Each fc In Sheets(1).Range("TableName[Column12]").FormatConditions
    fc.ModifyAppliesToRange Sheets(1).Range("TableName[Column13]")
Next fc
```

when i step through the Code, i can see that the change did in fact apply to the first rule, but on the second one it crashes. the condition rules are very simple and work for both columns if applied manually.

Comment: What does *crash* exactly mean? Does Excel just force close, do you get an error message or does it freeze? Specify a sheet for `Range("TableName[Column13]")` or Excel guesses which one you mean and might fail. • If Excel force closes: This means it is a bug in Excel (not in your code). In this case the only thing you can do is update to the most recent version. If it doesn't help re-install Office or try it on another computer.

Comment: It force Closes. I specified the sheet but it did not help. I updated the Question to include your suggestions

Comment: Well, as I said, force close means that there is a bug in Excel (which you cannot fix yourself, you just can update Excel) or something wrong with the installation on your computer. Try if it runs on another computer. If it crashes there too then it is very likely a bug in Excel. Make sure you update to the most recent version.

Comment: I tested this on different machines with different Excel versions (2013, 2016). I don't have Access to anything beyond 2016. It would be interesting to see if it worked on 365 though. i guess i'll have to work around this by deleting the old and adding new conditional formatting rules

Comment: Well this looks really like a bug in Excel. • Or a corrupt file. Try to reproduce the error in a blank new file. If it happens there too it is definitly a bug. If not your file might be corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug. I discovered that the folowing code works:

```
For fc = 1 To Sheets(1).Range("TableName[Column12]").FormatConditions.Count
   Sheets(1).Range("TableName[Column12]").FormatConditions(fc).ModifyAppliesToRange Sheets(1).Range("TableName[Column13]")
Next fc
```